# Azure Kubernetes, running DaemonSet to a pool "CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule"

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

i'm configuring Elastic Cloud agent on Azure AKS with pool system and user. On system pool i configured CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule taint to prevent that pod application run there. I installed the Elastic Cloud agent but i'm noticing that DaemonSet trying to run pods on that system pool without success. I tried to set on yaml config of agent the label CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule but i got same errors. Is there a way to force deploy on system pool or to exclude ElasticCloud pods deploy on that pool?

Here how setup yaml:

```
tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
          effect: NoSchedule
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: NoSchedule
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane` & `node-role.kubernetes.io/master` are no taints for AKS nodes. These are node labels. So please remove them from the toleration spec.

Furthermore specifying a toleration does not guarantee scheduling onto tolerated nodes. It just marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints. As your 2nd node pool seems not to be tainted, the scheduler just drops your pods there.

You could now add taints to your other nodepools or more easier just specify a node selector =

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.azure.com/mode: system
  tolerations:
    - key: "CriticalAddonsOnly"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
```

The same could be also achieved with [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity). You should check the Helm Chart or your deployment option if nodeSelector or NodeAffinity is available.